# vector sorting on the basis of first only

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Hey all I have a vector of pair. After sorting the vector (i.e. `sort(v.begin(),v.end())` .....It sorts the element on the basis of first element but there is a prob with me ...as I need to keep those element of second in same order whose first element are same ...for example look the following code..

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > v(2);
v[0].first = 1; v[1].first = 1;
v[0].second = 2; v[1].second = 0;
sort(v.begin(),v.end());
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    std::cout << v[i].first << " " << v[i].second << std::endl;
}
```

as output for the above code is

```
1 0
1 2
```

whereas i want the output as following

```
1 2
1 0
```

please help !!

Comment: No, this is **not** a duplicate, OP is asking for a stable sort (+ the dup is 7 years old : no need for boost anymore for this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) (to preserve your insertion order) with a custom comparer :

```
std::stable_sort(std::begin(v),
                 std::end(v),
                 [](const std::pair<int, int>& p1, const std::pair<int, int>& p2) { return p1.first < p2.first; });
```